# Why does LAZARUS open stdctrls.pp when I hit F9?

Tags: lazarus

I've been working on a project. I just hit F9 and instead of any results, the **stdctrls.pp** file gets opened on the IDE.

Why is this? It's the first time that this has happened.

In the messages window at the bottom, I see this message:

> stdctrls.pp(9,52) Fatal: Circular unit reference between StdCtrls and
>   LCLIntf

Answer (score 1):

Try shift+F9 (Rebuild All). It should rebuild whole project. In most cases it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your input. However, this never worked. Ctrl+F9, Shift+F9... I tried these methods. I ended up redoing the project as a new one.

Comment: Have you looked to those two files: StdCtrls and LCLIntf? Are they both in uses clause as it is said in error message?

Comment: Those files are not mine. They belong to Lazarus. I did not touch them. This is what puzzled me. Anyway I cannot trace this issue now as I have restarted the project.